# What is the meaning of different slimes in the Quick Save loading screen?

Tags: dragon-quest-9, dragon-quest-series

When loading from a Quick Save, there is an animation of 3 slimes in the bottom right corner of the screen.  Most of the time they're plain old blue slimes, but sometimes the middle one will be something else.  What is the significance of non-blue slimes here?

Comment: FWIW, I think there's some relation between a Blue-Metal-Blue loading slimes, and a map's quality or the quality of nearby treasure maps.  In the Level 86 Emerald World of Gloom (Kawasaki Locker) map, I consistently get Blue-Metal-Blue on floor B12 and below.

Answer (score 3):

First, read this thread about the hoimi table.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/55603529

WHen you get a Blue Blue Orange Slime loading screen, there are more red (2% rare luck) and blue squares (10% luck) in the hoimi table. Take a look at this picture:

http://blog-imgs-36-origin.fc2.com/d/r/a/drakue9/ssb1.png

Now, here is a hoimi table for another type of loading screen (Orange-Blue-Blue):

http://blog-imgs-36-origin.fc2.com/d/r/a/drakue9/bss2.png

As you can see there are a lot more red and blue squares in the first link than the 2nd pciture.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those images aren't loading for me - I'm getting 404 errors.